# How do I use the gcc -marm option in Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi

I am using Ubuntu in Raspberry Pi 4.

I understand that there is an option called -marm in gcc.
However, using the option to compile results in an error.

gcc error unrecognized command line option '-marm'

The development environment was installed through build-essential, and I wonder if additional settings are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because there is no `-marm` option in gcc. There is an `-march` option ( *arch* -> 'architecture' | https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GCC_optimization#-march) and an `-m` option ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/GNU_002fLinux-Options.html ) .

As RPi is based on an ARM the gcc has the following options : **https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options** ( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Submodel-Options.html#Submodel-Options **3.19 Machine-Dependent Options** )